# Which expression is the double pointer variable that always has the same memory size using sizeof()?

Tags: c, pointers, double, sizeof

While studying the pointer in C, I came across a certain code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    double d=5.3;
    double *dp;
    dp=&d;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(*dp)); 
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(dp)); 
    return 0;
}
```

The result using a 64-bit system would be `8 8`.

The reason I thought for this reason is because

1. `printf("%d\n", sizeof(*dp));`: `*dp` points the **value** which is a double type making it print `8`(byte)
2. `printf("%d\n", sizeof(dp));` : the `dp` is a pointer variable making it an `8`byte in a 64-bit system and `4`byte in a 32-bit system.

I'm wondering if what I understood is right or whether I got the reasons for 1 and 2 switched.

Comment: You understand correctly.

Comment: May be right, may not. Depends on your system. There is no 'right' answer; '64-bit' doesn't mean much.

Comment: side-note: pointers should be printed with `%zu`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons OP isn't printing any pointer. But you're right: `size_t` types should be printed with `%zu`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, brain error strikes again. I meant `size_t`.

Comment: both `double` and `pointer` sizes are implementation defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much got it:

```
sizeof  dp == sizeof (double *) == 8 (on your system)
sizeof *dp == sizeof (double)   == 8 (on your system)
```

On *your particular system*, both `double` and `double *` take up the same amount of space.  However, this doesn't have to be true.

Floating-point types must be able to represent a *minimum range of values* with a *minimum precision* - for `double`, it must be able to represent values in *at least* the range `1 x 10-37` to `1 x 1037` and provide *at least* 10 decimal digits of precision.  Most modern systems use IEEE-754 double-precision format, which meets those requirements and happens to take up 64 bits.

Pointer types are as big as they need to be to represent the address of an object or function of a specific type.  This can be affected by the number of address lines on the CPU, whether you're using a flat vs. segmented memory model, whether your platform is byte- or word-addressed, etc.  The only requirements are as follows:

- `char *` and `void *` have the same size and alignment;
- pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as pointers to their unqualified equivalent (e.g., `sizeof (const int *) == sizeof (int *)`);
- All pointers to `struct` types have the same size and alignment;
- All pointers to `union` types have the same size and alignment;

Beyond that, it's wide open.  It's possible to have systems where `sizeof (char *) != sizeof (int *)`, `sizeof (int *) != sizeof (int (*)[N])`, etc.

There are also Harvard architectures where code and data are kept in physically separate memory with different address bus sizes, so object pointers and function pointers may be different sizes.

Having said all that, you're most likely *not* working on anything that exotic.  On most modern desktop systems, all pointer types have the same size and representation.  Just be aware that's not guaranteed everywhere.

**Note**

The result of the `sizeof` operator has type `size_t`, which may be (and usually is) larger than `int`, so you should use the `%zu` conversion specifier to print it instead of `%d`:

```
printf( "sizeof *dp == %zu, sizeof (double) == %zu\n", sizeof *dp, sizeof (double) );
```

Remember that `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - you only need to use parentheses around the operand if it is a type name like `int` or `double`.